# on an iPhone web application: how do I disable the rectangle that appears around a DIV when a user touches and holds it?

Tags: javascript, iphone, touch

I've tried setting

> -webkit-user-select: none

and

> selectstart

And it did remove the selector, but a rectangle still appears..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the rectangle that appears on a link when you click it, then you can use this css rule to define the color and alpha of the rectangle. Use an alpha value of 0 to make it invisible:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS for the DIV, try using the outline property.

```
div.no-border {
    outline: none;
}
```